# How to pass additional property value with operator_menu_enum on execute?

Tags: python, operator

I have an operator with couple `EnumProperty` properties, all of them enumerate the same item list. I'd like to know which property changed on execution from [`layout.operator_menu_enum()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.UILayout.html#bpy.types.UILayout.operator_menu_enum).

With simple `layout.operator()` I can set it's property like this `layout.operator(...).some_property = "value"`, can I do something similar with `operator_menu_enum`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not Currently.

(2.79. sept 12-2017) `operator_menu_enum(....)` doesn't return the operator reference, so assigning something to `layout.operator_menu_enum(....).some_property='something'` will fail.

would be super handy if it did.